# NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest completionHandler fetching NSZeroData?

Tags: swift, nsdata, nsurlsession, swift-playground, stackexchange-api

I am trying to download some XML from the Stack Exchange API. However, I'm not getting any results back. The URL brings up the XML when accessed in the browser, but I can't seem to get that in the form of an NSData object. Or rather, I keep ending up with NSZeroData. Here is my code, note that it is written in Swift:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)

var myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: "api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"))

var mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

var dataTask = mySession.dataTaskWithRequest(myRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    var myData = data //myData now equals NSZeroData
})
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: did u find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"))
```

Diff is the protocol "http"

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me,

if your `customersString` in `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: customersString];` targets a **php-file** on your server (maybe a corner-case):

**Check, whether you use the right PHP-version** on your server! This can - for instance - be done with a new php-file:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

**Explanation:**

Your php-file may build your desired JSON (array) response not in a correct way, since php-version 5.4 builds arrays in a different way (compare: [Link to PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)):

```
<?php
    //before PHP 5.4
    $array = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
    );
    // since PHP 5.4
    $array = [
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
    ];
?>
```

This may lead to a **NSZeroData** response, due to that corrupted JSON.

**Thus:** Changing the PHP-version on my server solved the issue for me. Hope this helps!!!